# Python- how to return an index depending if there is an appearance in a list

Tags: python, list

So i have functions which output a random 5 digits (dice variable) i then have another variable which has a count that displays a number depending on how many of that certain number were in 'dice' e.g.
dice= [1, 3, 1, 4, 6] so then totals= [2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1] (because there is two 1's etc.)... my issue is that i need to make it that, If appearance is found in totals, the die’s score associated with that value is returned. If not, -1 is returned.

```
def countSame(appearances, totals):
    for appearances in totals:
        if appearances == True:
            return totals
        else:
            return -1
```

i cant seem to get my head around how to return the score (sorry im new)

Comment: Please don't use `if foo == True` - just use `if foo` to check for truthiness!

Comment: Can't get exactly what you require. Can you provide like a sample input and expected output for the code?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> dice = [1, 3, 1, 4, 6]
>>> counts = Counter(dice)
>>> counts
Counter({1: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1, 6: 1})
>>> totals = [counts.get(i, 0) for i in xrange(1, 7)]
>>> totals
[2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```